# How to get list of Endpoint Statistics and Dangerous Endpoints by using of Azure Mgmt SDK fluent

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-management-api

I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent for getting resources in Azure with programmatically(C#.NET-Core Web app) and tried to get resources information by providing service principals(CS) as below...

```
 string subscriptionId = "xxx";
            string clientId = "xxx";
            string tenantId = "xxx";
            string clientSecret = "xxx";

            AzureCredentials cred = new AzureCredentialsFactory()
                .FromServicePrincipal(
                clientId,
                clientSecret,
                tenantId,
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud
                );

            var azure = Azure.Configure()
                             .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                             .Authenticate(cred)
                             .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

Any sample code(C#.NET-Core Web app) to find out **Endpoint Statistics**( loop through open ports in NSG and list them in details) and **Dangerous Endpoints**(loop through open ports in NSG and identify ports like 3389/22).

Pls, advice on above.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide code what you have tried.

Comment: foreach (var nsg in azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.List())
                {
     foreach (var nic in nsg.NetworkInterfaceIds)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // how to find ind out Endpoint Statistics( loop through open ports in NSG and list them in details) 
       //and Dangerous Endpoints
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
     }

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami, just want to confirm, you want to list all the ports in NSG -> Inbound security rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean list all the ports in NSG -> Inbound security rules, like screenshot below:

[image]

Then you can use the code like below:

```
        foreach (var nsg in azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.List())
        {
            
            var rules = nsg.SecurityRules;

            foreach (var r in rules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"*** the NSG: {r.Value.Name} ***");

                if (r.Value.DestinationPortRange != null)
                {
                    //after you get the port, you can apply your logic here.
                    Console.WriteLine(r.Value.DestinationPortRange);
                }

                if (r.Value.DestinationPortRanges != null)
                {
                    foreach (var port in r.Value.DestinationPortRanges)
                    {
                        //after you get the port, you can apply your logic here.
                        Console.WriteLine(port);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("**end**");
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ivan Yang,, for response and help...

Below is working code, i modified urs code as per my

```
 var ntwrrkDetails = new List<EndTcpPorts>();  

   EndTcpPorts objEndTcpPorts; // cls object

  foreach (var nsg in azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.List())
                {
                    objEndTcpPorts = new EndTcpPorts();
                    objEndTcpPorts.ResourceGroup = nsg.ResourceGroupName.ToString();

                    try
                    {
                        var rules = nsg.SecurityRules;
                        foreach (var r in rules)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                objEndTcpPorts.NSGName = r.Value.Name.ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                objEndTcpPorts.NSGName = "";
                            }
                            if (r.Value.DestinationPortRanges != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    //get ports
                                    objEndTcpPorts.TcpPorts = r.Value.DestinationPortRange.ToString(); //((Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.IndexableWrapper<Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent.Models.SecurityRuleInner>)r.Value).Inner.Protocol.Value.ToString();
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                    objEndTcpPorts.TcpPorts = "";
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    ntwrrkDetails.Add(objEndTcpPorts); // add to list
                }
```

Now we can check(Dangerous Endpoints) in tcp ports as open ports in NSG and identify ports like 3389/22 or *..

Many Thanks,